# Доступ к разному контенту одной страницы по разным ссылкам. Как реализовать?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, url

Имеется пара **кнопок**

```html
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="main" class="menu main">Главная</div>
            <div id="news" class="menu news"> Новости</div>
            <div id="amalker" class="menu amalker">Реклама</div>
            <div id="managing" class="menu managing">Управление разделами</div>
        </div>
```

и несколько **разделов**, которые они открывают

```js
<div id = "content" >
  <div id = "tab_main" class = "ext_options" >
  </div> 
  <div id = "tab_news" class = "ext_options" >
  </div> 
  <div id = "tab_amalker"class = "ext_options" >
  </div> 
  <div id = "tab_create" class = "ext_options" >
  </div> 
</div>
```

Каким способом можно переходить к конкретным разделам сайта прямо из поисковика **Имея только одну лишь html страницу** по ссылкам типа:

`http://mysite.ru/main`

`http://mysite.ru/news`..?
Вроде как слышал, что можно использовать urlsearchParams..но это не точно

Answer (score 0):

например посредсвом URL якорей.

site.com/index.html#help - такая ссылка после открытия index.html отскролит к тегу с id='help'.

так же рекомендую глянуть на псевдокласс :target